# Count the number of datapoints in each "cell" of a grid

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count, grid

I have a dataframe with three columns, Subject, Rt1 and Rt2.

```
df<-data.frame(Subject = c(rep(1,15), rep(2,15)), RT1=rep(seq(100,1500,100),2), RT2 = rep(seq(200,3000,200),2))
```

For various reasons, I want to count the number/frequency of datapoints that fall on each cell of a 4*4 grid, for each subject. Here, the datapoints are the same for the 2 subjects, but for the actual data, it is not the case.

For example, let's say the value of my grid are :

```
x_axis <- c(220, 350, 700, 1250, 1800)
y_axis <- c(100, 700, 1400, 2500, 3500)
```

[image]

So basically I just want to get something that return me the number of point in each cell of the grid above, the desire output being something like :

```
df2<-data.frame("<x1"= c(1,0,0,0,0),
                "x1-x2"= c(0,2,0,0,0),
                "x2-x3"= c(0,0,4,0,0),
                "x4-x5"= c(0,0,0,3,0)
                )
```

Please note that this example is only for one subject (for clarity sake)

I do know how to do this, by simply counting the number of point in each "case", like :

```
df%>%
  group_by(Subject)%>%
  count(between(df$RT1,0,180),between(df$RT2 ,0,210))%>%
  set_names(c("RT1","RT2","n"))%>%
  filter(if_all(RT1:RT2, ~ . %in% TRUE))
```

However this is highly inefficient, as I should paste this code for each and every cell of all of my conditions.

I also have a solution using table and cut, but I don't know how to group by subject with this method :

```
table(
  cut(df$RT2, c(0, y_axis), right = FALSE),
  cut(df$RT1, c(0, x_axis), right = FALSE)
)
```

Update: If you can make it work grouped by Subject, that would be amazing!

```
df<-data.frame(Subject = c(rep(1,15), rep(2,15)), RT1=rep(seq(100,1500,100),2), RT2 = rep(seq(200,3000,200),2))
```

Comment: Is there any correspondence between RT1-x_axis and RT2-y_axis? Or maybe you are looking for RT1 and RT2 to cross both x_axis and y_axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. Use the `cut()` function to break `RT1` and `RT2` into groups, according to the slices set out in `x_axis` and `y_axis`
2. Get the count of each x and y group we just created.

```
out <- df |> 
  mutate(x = cut(RT1, c(0, x_axis), labels = x_axis),
            y = cut(RT2, y_axis, labels = y_axis[-1])) |>
            count(x, y)
```

For multiple subjects, we literally add two words:

```
df |> 
  mutate(x = cut(RT1, c(0, x_axis), labels = x_axis),
            y = cut(RT2, y_axis, labels = y_axis[-1]), .by = Subject) |>
            count(x, y, Subject)
```

Output for original:

```
     x    y  n
1  220  700  4
2  350  700  2
3  700 1400  8
4 1250 2500 10
5 1800 3500  6
```

If you *insist* on it being in the wider format, (despite it being untidy/bad practice to store data like this, and the zeroes just adding more clutter imo), you can use `pivot_wider()`:

```
out |> pivot_wider(names_from= y, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  x     `700` `1400` `2500` `3500`
  <fct> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 220       4      0      0      0
2 350       2      0      0      0
3 700       0      8      0      0
4 1250      0      0     10      0
5 1800      0      0      0      6
```

Notes:

- My table is slightly different to your table, because it appears that the cuts in your y_axis are slightly different from the ones in your screenshot (and presumably your output). The smallest one is 100 in your input, but in the plot it's around 220.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough because the example that you choose has many coincidences that could lead to misunderstandings.

- 2 columns excluding the subject (`RT1`, `RT1`). 2 vector for comparison (`x_axis`, `y_axis`). 2 subjects in `df`. Is there any correspondence between them?
- In `df2` each row represents the number (frequency) of individuals that were within a range, but this does not have too much sense because 1 number will be categorized in 1 range only, so the zeros in `df2` represent something that is obvious I think.
- Why you did not considered the range **x3-x4** in `df2`, I could suppose it was a mistake but in your example this is one of the ranges with more individuals.

So, assuming that there is a correspondence: `RT1`-`x_axis` and `RT2`-`y_axis`, I could suggest next solution. I could improve it, but it is required that you give us a better example or explanation.

```
mapply(x = df[,2:3], breaks = list(x_axis = x_axis, y_axis = y_axis), 
       FUN = \(x, breaks) cut(x = x, breaks = c(-Inf, breaks, Inf)), 
       SIMPLIFY = FALSE) |> 
  
  lapply(\(x) table(df$Subject, x))
```

In the output, each column is a range (taking into account the assumed correspondence) and each row is a subject.

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of clarity of this post. Here are the answer : 1) There is no correspondance between the values in RT1 & RT2 and the values in x_axis and y_axis, that is the values in the vector have nothing to do with df. I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "correspondance" 2) The row of df2 represents the intervals of the y_axis vector, that is <y1 ; y1-y2 etc 3) yes, I forgot the range x3-x4