# Use cut function with a list instead of a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count, grid

I have a df with 3 columns, Subject, RT1 and RT2.
Here is an oversimplified df. Note that RT1 and RT2 are not actually related.

```
df<-data.frame(Subject = c(rep(1,15), rep(2,15)), RT1=rep(seq(100,1500,100),2), RT2 = rep(seq(200,3000,200),2))
```

I want to count,for each subject, the number/frequency of datapoints that fall on each cell of a 4*4 grid.
The trick is, for each subject, the bins are different (I got them in another df) :

```
#simplified example
df2<-data.frame(Subject = c(1,2),
 B1 = c(100,110),
 B2 = c(150,168),
 B3 = c(450,624),
B4 = c(960,1278))`

df3<-data.frame(Subject = c(1,2),
 B1 = c(240,246),
 B2 = c(450,378),
 B3 = c(624,670),
B4 = c(1145,1681))`
```

How can I make the cut() function change it's bins values for each ppt ?

For now,my code is :

```
df|>
  group_by(Subject)%>%
  mutate(x = cut(RT1,breaks=c(0,df2,Inf), labels = c(df2,">max")),
         y=cut(RT2,breaks=c(0,df3,Inf), labels = c(df3,">max"))) |>
  count(x,y, .drop=FALSE)

#with 

df2<-c(110,200,300,500)
df3<-c(250,450,720,1500)
```

I'm sorry if anything is unclear, this is fairly complicated to explain.
I would really appreciate any help on this topic.
Thanks,

Lucas

Comment: Why do you think `cut` is the function you need to use? Why do you think yuo need to make it work with a list? Could you provide your expected results

Comment: I think I need cut() with a list beacuse it's thé fonction I'm using when the bins are the same for every subjects. However, if there is another way to count the number of points in each cell of a grid, I Can use or as well. The desired output would be the same than the one from my current code. However, the values should be differents.

Comment: Include the desired results with the expected values. Note that we are unable to help if we do not understand what you are doing and what your goal is. You might be thinking of cut and probably its the wrong way to think about it since cut does not use lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the number of datapoints in each "cell" of a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77177164/count-the-number-of-datapoints-in-each-cell-of-a-grid)

Comment: with the simplified example, the first bin is 100,110, and the second bin is 150,168. Does this mean you want to throw out all numbers below 100 and those between 110 and 168?

Comment: Mark, the question you refer to is my own actually. Because the opération I want to make is complex, I've built it step by step. S

Comment: I'm aware! I don't see the difference between it and this one, except the input being slightly different

Comment: with the simplified example, the first bin is 100,110, and the second bin is 150,168. Does this mean you want to throw out all numbers below 100 and those between 110 and 168?

Comment: I was interrupted midway through, sorry. So, My task is the same as in the question you refer to. However, in the first one, I I wanted to count, for each subject, the number of points in each cell of a grid, with the breaks of this grid being the same for all of the subjects. But now, I would like to know the way to change the breaks of that grid, for each subject. That is, for Subject 1, I want to count how many obervation there is with RT1 in [100;150[ AND RT2 in [240;450[ (1st cell) ; but for  S2, the bins would be RT1 in [110;168[ and RT2 in [246;378[. Is it more clear ?

Comment: I think so? It sounds like you want to do the same thing, but group it by subject

Comment: That's it, but how can I use the cut() function to use differents bins values for each subject ? When I use a dataframe instead of a vector in the "breaks" parameter of cut(), it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @L_ROTOLO. I updated the original question's answer to include grouping by subject. To use the dataframe of bins sizes, you can just use the rows e.g. df2[1,-1]

Comment: "*it won't work*" sure it will!

Comment: I've litteraly deleted this when I saw your last comment (I just saw the upadte on the question at first). Your answer is really usefull, thank for the time you put to help me !

Comment: no worries! If you want to use things seamlessly, you probably want to turn the breaks into a list column, and then do a left join, so each row of df has a breaks vector. Let me know if you have any more issues

Comment: After a closer examination of the data, we're not done yet (sorry). Your method works by providing the same bins to each subject, that is the first row of df2. However, I would like to have this for s1, but to have the values of the second row of df2 as bins for subject2, the values of the third row for subject3, etc.

Comment: where does df3 come into this?

Comment: in the previous question, I mentionned that my aim is to count the number of rows with rt1 in [100;150[ and rt2 in [200;250[ ; then rt1 in [150; 350[ and rt2 in [200;250[ etc, with 5 bins for rt1 and 5 bins for rt2. The values of the RT1 bins are specify in df2 (5 columns, a row per participant) ; the values of the RT2 bins are specify in df3.